# See if file reads something in Java

Tags: java, string-matching

I created a document called doc.txt, and in it I wrote "blaha". I wrote a program to see if it says blaha.

```
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Public/doc.txt");
    if (file.exists()){
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
     LineNumberReader ln = new LineNumberReader(fr);
        while (ln.getLineNumber() == 0){
          String s = ln.readLine();
          System.out.println(s);
          if(s=="blaha"){
              System.out.println("Match");
          }else{
              System.out.println("Nomatch");
          }
    }
    }
```

And when I run the program, it always says Nomatch. Why is this?

Comment: Compare `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 6):

To compare strings for value *equality* (whether two objects have the same value) do this:

```
s.equals("blaha")
```

The `==` operator tests for reference *identity* (whether two objects are one and the same). Most of the time, you're interested in equality.

Comment: Also, for more jargon, `==` for reference equality, `.equals()` for value equality.

Answer (score 1):

Because blaha != trollface.  Also, you're going to want to make that more robust to handle trailing white space.  You probably want to use trim() on the string.  Also, use String.equals() or string.contains().

Comment: Sorry, when I originally used trollface, but didn't want to post that on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all always use .equals. No ifs and no buts. Read this for details: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AvoidTheEqualityOperator